# How to Compare Pointers in LLVM-IR?

Tags: pointers, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to analyze the pointer values in LLVM IR.

As illustrated in [LLVM Value Class](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html),

> `Value` is is a very important LLVM class. It is the base class of all
>   values computed by a program that may be used as operands to other
>   values. Value is the super class of other important classes such as
>   Instruction and Function. All Values have a Type. Type is not a
>   subclass of Value. Some values can have a name and they belong to some
>   Module. Setting the name on the Value automatically updates the
>   module's symbol table.

To test if a `Value` is a pointer or not, there is a function `a->getType()->isPointerTy()`. LLVM also provides a [LLVM PointerType class](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PointerType.html), however there are not direct apis to compare the values of pointers.

So I wonder how to compare these pointer values, to test if they are equal or not. I know there is `AliasAnalysis`, but I have doubt with the `AliasAnalysis` results, so I want to validate it myself.

Answer (score 5):

The quick solution is to use `IRBuilder::CreatePtrDiff`. This will compute the difference between the two pointers, and return an `i64` result. If the pointers are equal, this will be zero, and otherwise, it will be nonzero.

It might seem excessive, seeing as `CreatePtrDiff` will make an extra effort to compute the result in terms of number of *elements* rather than number of *bytes*, but in all likelihood that extra division will get optimized out.

The other option is to use a `ptrtoint` instruction, with a reasonably large result type such as `i64`, and then do an integer comparison.

From the online reference:

```
Value *     CreatePtrDiff (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="")
Return the i64 difference between two pointer values, dividing out the size of the pointed-to objects.
```